# no such option --rosdep-install

Tags: ros, rosmake, vslam, rosdep-install

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am attempting to install the source code modifiable version of VSLAM. I need to run "rosmake --rosdep-install vslam_system" and it fails with this error
yglee@yglee-VirtualBox:~/ros_workspace/VSLAMDIR$ rosmake --rosdep-install vslam_system
Usage: rosmake [options] [PACKAGE]...

rosmake: error: no such option: --rosdep-install

I have rosdep downloaded via pip and easy_install (I tried both just incase). Does anyone know why rosmake doesn't find the option rosdep?

Thanks,

Grace

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38291/no-such-option---rosdep-install/) by [yglee](https://answers.ros.org/users/2776/yglee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2012-07-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Internal use of rosdep inside rosmake was removed in ROS Fuerte (see [REP 125](http://ros.org/reps/rep-0125.html#rosmake))

You'll now have to use

```
rosdep install PACKAGE
rosmake PACKAGE
```

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2012-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3